# How do you read zeros in abbreviated years? (i.e. ０３年)

Tags: readings, numbers

I came across `０３年度` and `０９年度`, and while the meaning is clear I didn't know the actual way of reading it. My first reaction was `ゼロさんねんど`, but I have no way of checking if that's right. I thought it might also be simply, `さんねんど`, but again I can't tell.

Comment: http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail.php?qid=1480530149
知恵袋で聞いてみました(他力本願？えへっ^^)いい答えが返ってくればいいのだけど・・・

Answer (score 5):

I think we usually read them as さんねんど, きゅうねんど etc. I've never heard anyone say ゼロさんねんど or ゼロきゅうねんど.　I think we write that way to differentiate （西暦/A.D.）０３年度 from （平成）３年度.

Comment: I would read it as ゼロさんねんど and ゼロきゅうねんど, and I have never imagined anyone would read differently (because of my lack of imagination).

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto san, Ah, really... Sorry it may be because I've never worked for a 'company' so maybe I just don't know it... I'll try to do some research and add some more information if I find anything... (or else maybe I'll take back my post...)

Comment: Just in case, I do not know if ゼロさんねんど is more common than さんねんど.  I had been simply assuming incorrectly that everyone reads it as ゼロさんねんど.  So please do not remove the post because of my comment.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto san...誰かもう少し良い回答を寄せて欲しいと待っていますが・・誰も来ません。難しい質問なのでしょうか。ビジネスマンとかで詳しい人いそうなのに・・